# Slahs-commands ephemeral doesn't send hidden message python

Tags: pycord

`await ctx.respond("Test", ephemeral = True)`

this code is sending public message to discord channel but I wanna send hidden message. I dont know why?

Answer (score 0):

because ephemeral responses are only for slash commands.

Comment: Yeah I am using ephemeral for slash commands

Answer (score 0):

I found answer of my question that is why ephemeral doesn't work on slash Commands. Beacuse of arg.DeferAsync(). That is rule. If you use arg.DeferAsync() with ephemeral. Ephemeral will not work.